# Connecting my application to Google Drive for test accounts?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I'm setting up my application in Google Marketplace.

I would like to test [creating a document with my application](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-create).

I want to know - how can I connect my application to Google Drive Create menu for [certain test users](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/publish?csw=1#testaccounts)?

- I published my application to specific test group of users
- I sign-in as one of the test users
- Click on a direct link to install my application.
- Install my application.
- Go to Google Drive - click Create I don't see my application in the list.

If I can't connect my application for test users, how does one test create/open files for an application? Direct links?

**update:** When I go to Setttings -> Manage apps, I see my application in the list as one of the connected applications. However when I try to open it via Create menu, it's not shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, missed a form field "Create URL" in [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). By specifying Create URL, the app now shows up in Create New menu. [image]